# How to use dplyr & casewhen, across groups and rows, with three outcomes?

Tags: r, dplyr

This seems a simple question to me but I'm super stuck on it! My data looks like this:

```
 Name round  MatchNumber Score
   <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 A         1     1    48
 2 B         1     1    66
 3 C         1     2    74
 4 D         1     2    62
 5 E         1     3    61
 6 F         1     3    63
 7 G         1     4    63
 8 H         1     4    63
 9 E         2     1    51
10 D         2     1    59
11 A         2     2    50
12 H         2     2    78
13 B         2     3    51
14 G         2     3    47
15 C         2     4    72
16 F         2     4    73
```

All I want to do is create a new column `Outcome` from `Score` to designate that for every name, round and match, there is a Win/ Loss or Draw. Ideally, this would be done via `dplyr` and likely via `casewhen` but I just can't get my head around the row-wise calculation and grouping. I've tried (but am stuck at) the following:

```
MatchOutcome <- ExampleData %>%  
  arrange(round, MatchNumber) %>% 
  group_by(Name, round, MatchNumber) %>% 
  mutate(Outcome = Score)
```

My ideal output would look like:

```
Name round  MatchNumber Score Outcome
       <chr>   <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>
     1 A         1     1    48    Loss
     2 B         1     1    66    Win
     3 C         1     2    74    Win
     4 D         1     2    62    Loss
     5 E         1     3    61    Loss
     6 F         1     3    63    Win
     7 G         1     4    63    Draw
     8 H         1     4    63    Draw
     9 E         2     1    51    Loss
    10 D         2     1    59    Win
    11 A         2     2    50    Loss
    12 H         2     2    78    Win
    13 B         2     3    51    Win
    14 G         2     3    47    Loss
    15 C         2     4    72    Loss
    16 F         2     4    73    Win
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
ExampleData %>%
  group_by(round, MatchNumber) %>%
  mutate(Outcome = case_when(Score == mean(Score) ~ "Draw",
                             Score == max(Score) ~ "Win",
                             TRUE ~ "Loss")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 5
   Name  round MatchNumber Score Outcome
   <chr> <int>       <int> <int> <chr>  
 1 A         1           1    48 Lose   
 2 B         1           1    66 Win    
 3 C         1           2    74 Win    
 4 D         1           2    62 Lose   
 5 E         1           3    61 Lose   
 6 F         1           3    63 Win    
 7 G         1           4    63 Draw   
 8 H         1           4    63 Draw   
 9 E         2           1    51 Lose   
10 D         2           1    59 Win    
11 A         2           2    50 Lose   
12 H         2           2    78 Win    
13 B         2           3    51 Win    
14 G         2           3    47 Lose   
15 C         2           4    72 Lose   
16 F         2           4    73 Win
```

Data:

```
ExampleData <- read.table(text = "Name round  MatchNumber Score
 1 A         1     1    48
 2 B         1     1    66
 3 C         1     2    74
 4 D         1     2    62
 5 E         1     3    61
 6 F         1     3    63
 7 G         1     4    63
 8 H         1     4    63
 9 E         2     1    51
10 D         2     1    59
11 A         2     2    50
12 H         2     2    78
13 B         2     3    51
14 G         2     3    47
15 C         2     4    72
16 F         2     4    73")
```

Comment: Apologies, human error! I wrote draw instead of loss. Thanks so much :-)

Comment: Cool. Glad you found it useful :)